# Cross-Platform Console Clearing?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, windows

What do I need to do if I want to clear the console without OS-Limitations?
I know that on Linux and Mac the command "clear" exists, whereas Windows has "cls".
I want to clear the console every now and then on the three major systems without personally choosing "clear" or "cls".

My idea so far was

```
import platform
os = platform.system()
if os == "Windows":
    clear = 'cls'
else:
    clear = 'clear'
```

and then just use clear as variable for both, depending on the OS, but it doesn't work. Is something like this actually possible?

Comment: Seems there is no better way, just different syntactical variations of what you've proposed - see the duplicate and other questions, which should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accuracy use `sys` and as a good practice use `subprocess`

```
#usr/bin/env python

from sys import platform
from subprocess import run

command = {'win32': 'cls', 'linux': 'clear'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
     run(command[platform], shell=True)
```

As BartoszKP said there are many ways of doing this, I find this a very clean way of doing it.

Comment: And for instance, your code snippet does work.

Comment: I feel a bit ashamed now. I checked my code again and realized that I shouldn't use "os" as variable when I want to call "os.system(clear)"...